# Midnight Commander on Mac - Compare files doesn't work

Tags: mac, midnight-commander

In the latest Midnight Commander version (4.8.30) installed with Brew on Mac M2 compare files doesn't work. Seems it tried to call diff with unrecognized option.
[image: mc after call compare files]

command `diff --version` show: Apple diff (based on FreeBSD diff)

Answer (score 2):

Midnight Commander use console "diff" internally to compare files.
MacOS 14 Sonoma (as well as previous) provide very old version of "diff".
To fix you need to install diff:

```
brew install diffutils
```